# SQL Server : search by first 3 words and last 3 words in a multi join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL Server statement that searches for the first 3 words and also the last 3 words in a string that starts with something.

Example: `19032560951039OHUG` I want to use `**HUG**` as the search parameter
also for `400305` I want to use `400`

I had already tried it but it was returning an empty query.

First: The **main query**

```
select * 
from memtrans 
where right(trx_no, 3) = 'HUG' 
  and left(gl_no, 3)= '400'
```

Table for **main query**

[image]

When I write a join query with the main query:

```
select 
    custinfo.SavOfficer, 
   -sum(memtrans.amount) as feencharges
from  
    memtrans 
inner join
    custinfo on memtrans.ac_no = custinfo.cust_no
where
    right(memtrans.trx_no, 3) = 'HUG' 
    and left(memtrans.gl_no, 3)= '400'
group by
    custinfo.SavOfficer
```

Which returned empty result. But if I remove the WHERE clause, results will be return

```
select 
    custinfo.SavOfficer,
    -sum(memtrans.amount) as feencharges
from 
    memtrans 
inner join
    custinfo on memtrans.ac_no = custinfo.cust_no
group by 
    custinfo.SavOfficer
```

Table sample for query without the WHERE clause

[image]

**custinfo** table

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "first 3 *letters* and last 3 *letters* in a " char/nchar/varchar/nvarchar(*) field? I was going to edit but felt a question in a comment was better. However, I would recommend you sould try this for a where clause:   WHERE memtrans.tx_no LIKE '400%HUG'

Comment: Please check my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your **images** I can't see why that query would return 0 rows. If you post your sample data as DDL and DML statements, that replicate the problem, that'll be really helpful.

Comment: (*Although, I **assume** that the data type of `trx_no` is a `(n)varchar` and not a `(n)char`, and that it has no trailing spaces*)

Comment: Ah, I misread! Maybe try adding: memtrans.trx_no,  right(memtrans.trx_no,3) , memtrans.gl_no, left(memtrans.gl_no,3) to your query to test the join is working as expected. It's possible that there is some type coercion - what type is the GL column?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the help. My client gave a wrong transaction code unknown to him they have changed some of the table structures which resulted to a different transaction codes. After delving deep into it I was able to pull the results using different code.

Previous code

```
select custinfo.SavOfficer,
  -SUM(memtrans.amount) AS feencharges
   FROM memtrans 
  INNER JOIN 
  custinfo
  ON  memtrans.ac_no = custinfo.cust_no
  WHERE
   right(memtrans.trx_no,3) = 'HUG' 
   AND left(memtrans.gl_no,3)= '400'
  GROUP BY custinfo.SavOfficer
```

New code:

```
select custinfo.SavOfficer,
 -SUM(memtrans.amount) AS feencharges
 from memtrans 
inner join 
custinfo
on  memtrans.ac_no = custinfo.cust_no
where
 right(memtrans.trx_no,3) = 'HUG' or right(memtrans.trx_no,1) = 'N'

group by custinfo.SavOfficer
```

Much appreciation goes to **@mgrollins** and **@Larnu** for there time.

Comment: Glad to be able to help Olajumoke! Glad you were able to get this figured out!

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for both 400 and hug this should work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
memtrans
INNER JOIN 
custinfo
ON  memtrans.ac_no = custinfo.cust_no
WHERE RIGHT(trx_no, 3) = 'HUG'
AND LEFT(trx_no, 3) = '400'
```

If you are looking for either 400 or hug use this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
memtrans
INNER JOIN 
custinfo
ON  memtrans.ac_no = custinfo.cust_no
WHERE RIGHT(trx_no, 3) = 'HUG' 
AND LEFT(trx_no, 3) = '400'
```